# How to deploy to all resources in an environment in Azure DevOps yaml pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to run a yaml build and deploy pipeline in Azure DevOps. Everything is working correctly except the CopyFiles step in my deployment job.

If I define a specific resource in the deployment.environment step (e.g. environment: DEV.VM123) then everything works as expected on that machine. If I try to just use the environment name (i.e. environment: DEV), then nothing really happens.

The documentation seems to indicate that if you just use an environment name then the deployment job would run on all resources in that environment, but instead I get nothing. I'd rather not have to set the actual resource name in the pipeline in case I switch to a different VM at some point.

**Works**

```
- stage: Dev
  variables:
    - group: development
  jobs:
  - deployment: 
    displayName: Dev Deploy
    environment: DEV.VM123
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: echo running the dev deployment
              displayName: Running dev deployment
            - task: CopyFiles@2
              displayName: 'Copy Package to: temp'
              inputs:
                SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ClientApp/'
                Contents: '**'
                TargetFolder: 'C:\temp\client_deploy\'
                CleanTargetFolder: true
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
- stage: Dev
  variables:
    - group: development
  jobs:
  - deployment: 
    displayName: Dev Deploy
    environment: DEV
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: echo running the dev deployment
              displayName: Running dev deployment
            - task: CopyFiles@2
              displayName: 'Copy Package to: temp'
              inputs:
                SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ClientApp/'
                Contents: '**'
                TargetFolder: 'C:\temp\client_deploy\'
                CleanTargetFolder: true
```

Comment: Ho Ho @JumboMaximus! Curiosity, did you found a way? We are in the same situation. Thank you!

Comment: Finally, we used tags with the same name of the environment.

Comment: @TomSawyer could you elaborate or provide a link please? 

Comment: @Cocowalla We add a tag "dev" on all servers (resource) in the environment "dev" then we use it like this in the yaml: - deployment: Deployment \n\t environment: \n\t\t name: dev \n\t\t tags: dev \n\t\t resourceType: VirtualMachine  . Does this solve the issue?